# Isolated vs non-isolated boost converter for LED (12v to 24v)

Tags: led, dc, pwm, dc-dc-converter, led-strip

I have a 12v system in my motorhome and planning on installing 24v LED strips, however, I'm unsure whether I would need an isolated or a non-isolated boost converter.

I'll be using roughly 5 meters of LED (24W per meter).

If I would have to choose all by myself after reading on StackExchange I would go for a non-isolated converter as this is not a critical application and we're only talking about direct current. However, I'd like somebody to confirm my thinking.

So my questions.

1. Isolated or Non-Isolated 12v to 24v Boost Converter? ([Victron Orion](https://www.victronenergy.com/dc-dc-converters))
2. I might add a PWM Dimmer in the 24v circuit. Does that change anything?
3. I do have 230V AC in my motorhome (from an inverter). Would it be a better choice of using a simple LED Driver that converts AC to DC?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the ground return route through the chassis? Are you expecting to use a radio, for example an AM band radio, when this lighting system is operating?

Comment: Nope, the return route is through a wire. Well, did not think of that, to be honest. This would be at the back of the vehicle and the radio (and antenna) in front. Is that any help? The radio is powered from the starter battery and the lights are from the house battery. What would be the consequences if I would use that radio?

Comment: Why not use 12V strips?  There are plenty of them available.

Comment: I'd like to use a led strip that is "no-spotting" or "seamless". So that there are no "black spots" when I look at it. There is not much distance between the LED and the actual plastic diffuser in the aluminum profile. Therefore, I need something that comes with very short distance between the LEDs and at least 240LEDs per meter. I could not find one that is 12V unfortunately.